# claws mail - modify email headers through an external program - for HTML messages

Tags: email-client, mime-types, claws-mail

In [Claws Mail](http://www.claws-mail.org), is there any way to insert / modify headers through an external program?

According to [this documentation on Actions](http://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Actions), there does not seem to be any way to do this.  Specifically, when running an action on a message that is being composed, all the ways of feeding the entire message text (rather than just the message body) to a script are barred from usage.

I ask because I would like to implement my own kludge for composing HTML mail on Claws.  The developers have [their own very valid reasons](http://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/General_Information#Does_Claws_Mail_allow_me_to_write_HTML_styled_messages.3F) for not implementing HTML composition in claws.  However, it would be simple to write a bash script to convert a Markdown formatted email into HTML and insert the HTML version below a multipart alternative header.  If this is implemented as an action on message text, Claws can simply send the email with both parts.  However, in order for this message to be read properly, Claws has to also permit my script to add in a "Content-Type: multipart/alternative" header into the headers of the message.  I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Well, you must pay some kind of penance for sending html mail, surely? :)

Comment: So, did you find a solution? I would be really interested in a follow-up. [-: Cheers.

Comment: Nope :), except for the possibility below, which seemed too inconvenient for regular usage...

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible using Actions. Attach an html file, queue it, then use an Action. The Action command would be '/path/to/my/script %f&' and the script would modify (it wouldn't need to add) the headers.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea - did not think of the fact that Actions can run on the Queue folder (one wouldn't even need to attach an HTML file separately; the script can do that).  Though this does not make for a very convenient workflow (I was hoping for a single keyboard shortcut on any mail).  If it works when I try it will accept your answer :)

Comment: In fact the required workflow would really be a pain - one would have to choose "send later", go into the queue folder, choose the message, trigger the action, and then send the message.  Perhaps worth it for rare messages.  But would be so much easier with an action from the compose window... sigh :)